# Php does not Post Data From json please

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My Php seems not to be sending to database below is php code I want to get MerchantRequest_ID only

```
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","adflix","[4bTR9Hdp") or die('Database Not Connected. Please Fix the Issue! ' . mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("njec_flix", $connect);
    $str  = file_get_contents('beit.json');
    $json = json_decode($str, true);

    $MerchantRequest_ID = $str['body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequest_ID']; 



    $query = "INSERT INTO test(MerchantRequest_ID) VALUES('$MerchantRequest_ID')";
    if(!mysql_query($query,$connect)) { 
        die('Error : Query Not Executed. Please Fix the Issue! ' . mysql_error());
    } else{ echo "Data Inserted Successully!!!";
    } 
?>
```

my Json from beit.json

```
{
    "Body":{
        "stkCallback":{
            "RequestID3":"11623-8633880-1",
            "MerchantRequest_ID":
            "ws_CO_DMZ_336620817_07022019155939425",
            "ResultCode":1036,
            "ResultDesc":"[STK_CB - ]SMSC ACK timeout."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `['body']` is not `"Body"`

Comment: should that not be `$MerchantRequest_ID = $json['body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequest_ID'];` ~ note using `$json` rather than `$str`

Comment: note : you should redact your credentials when posting to an open forum like this.

Comment: `mysql` api is depricated,please move on to `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: @RamRaider lol , just with the 'body' proviso, but i missed the obvious.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Thanks to you all  you really saved me  alot of thinking i found out small mistake like 'body not same as Body' and also changed mysql to sqli  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$str` contains string read from your JSON file, if you wanna read a property of the objet you must use the `$json` var.

That's **not**:

`$MerchantRequest_ID = $str['body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequest_ID'];`

**but**

`$MerchantRequest_ID = $json['body']['stkCallback']['MerchantRequest_ID'];`